# Overlaying slider element on top of CardView

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to build a slider that slides on top of my current view in Android. I built the slider using the SlideUp library found here https://github.com/mancj/SlideUp-Android. The slider is taking the inner RelativeLayout as a view source. When I pull up the slider it ends up behind the CardView. I've looked through all the methods in the library and there isn't one that allows you to move the slider to the foreground. I've also tried to bring the slider view to foreground with `.bringToFront()` method. Moving the slider view before the CardView in the .xml file does nothing either. Is there a good way to bring the slider to foreground... or the CardView in the background? (without hiding the CardView)

JAVA

```
//code to build slider
View slideView = findViewById(R.id.slider);
//tried putting slideView.bringToFront() here before passing it to the object but that did nothing

SlideUp slideUp = new SlideUpBuilder(slideView)
        .withStartState(SlideUp.State.HIDDEN)
        .withStartGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM)
        .build();

//code to bring up slider. View "share" exists, it's just irrelevant so I didn't include in the .xml file
buttonView.findViewById(R.id.share).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //tried putting slideView.bringToFront() here as well
            slideUp.toggle(); //toggles slider up/down
        }
    });
```

XML

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp">
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:background="@color/primary">
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I found out I can add `android:elevation="2dp"` for the slider and 0dp for the CardView